# Discord API users/@me always returns same user object even when logged into another user

Tags: discord

I am trying to get user emails via the Discord API OAuth2 Authentication Flow (regular application not a bot).

I can successfully complete the OAuth2 flow and have a user allow permissions to let my application view their email. I will be using a test account under the email mmaines@cisco.com (2nd test user).

However even when i am logged in as a completely different user, and follow the OAuth2 flow getting a access token back, the [api/v6/users/@me](https://github.com/GregTCLTK/Discord-Api-Endpoints/issues/10#issuecomment-1053605945) endpoint always returns the original user object of my 2 test users (even if it should not even have access to that account since the access token is for the second test user).

Below I will walk you through the whole process I am using

**OAuth2 Authorization URL Using 2nd Test Account**

[OAuth2 Authorization URL Using 2nd Test Account Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5yFr.png)

in the linked screenshot, notice the email that is being requested here is mmaines@cisco.com

**server.js (Callback for Authorization Code)**

Here is my callback from the OAuth2 Authorization

```
server.get('/auth/discord/callback', function(req, res) {

    const discordUID = req.query.state;

    // Get the access token with email and identify scopes on the mmaines-cisco user
    axios.post(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=344539394373582849&client_secret=Cck2cchaqQiLCRASTXhcDwHZscNFLW7u&code=${req.query.code}&scope=email+identify&state=${req.query.state}`, {})
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);

        res.cookie("access_token", response.data.access_token);
        res.redirect("/discord/tag-email/");

    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });

});
```

**Access_Token Recieved**

```
{ 
    access_token: 'loUOWKzOgUj45PSkbGoXUFgY6wQS52',
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    state: '347013221682511873',
    expires_in: 604800,
    scope: 'email identify' 
}
```

Above is the response from the /api/oauth2/token endpoint, notice the access_token and notice the state key which is carrying over the Discord userID of the user who verified access to their email

**Redirect Page**

This page is where the user ends up after accepting the authorization and giving access to their email and user information. Here I am running the api request on the client to make absolutely sure that the /users/@me resource is their account

note that the access_token is passed to the client as a cookie (I have also tried passing it as a url parameter and that has the same result)

**index.hbs**

```
<h1>Thank You!</h1>
<h3>Your membership is being unlocked now!</h3>

{{access_token}}

<script>
    console.log(`Bearer {{access_token}}`);
    axios.get(`https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me`, {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer {{access_token}}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log("USER: ", response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
</script>
```

**ScreenShot of Index Route After User Authorization and Received User Object From Discord API**

[ScreenShot of the recieved user object from the Discord API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTha0.png)

Please note that the **username**, **user-id**, and **email** are all different from the expected values (these are the values from my primary test account). I am logged out of the primary test account in ALL discord clients and am logged into the web client as my second test user.

Also please note that the printed out access_token is the same one we received from the api after getting authorization for the second test account

**The Question**

I am not sure why the api/v6/users/@me endpoint returns a user object in which

1. the access_token should not even have access to the primary test account info
2. is not returning the user info from the user logged in at the time of the api call

Any ideas on why this is? Thank you for reading this far, and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This could be some weird caching issue - have you tried using another web browser just to confirm that's not the case?

Comment: You shouldn't be posting your oauth2 secret online. If it is valid, please reset it.

Comment: @Indigo I think this may be the case. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Fre_d Thanks for pointing that out, I though I replaced it with <client_secret> but i guess I missed that in the heat of the moment lol. I have already recreated a new secret. Thanks : )

Comment: Hello @mmaines. Did you finally solve this issue? I'm having the exact same issue right now...

Comment: @EricMcWinNEr I am baffled, I have been experiencing this. It always returns my main accounts user object and not the person who just authorised against OAuth. I am truly baffled, I have tried 3 different browsers and my code is pretty much the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but i encountered the same weird issue where i always received the same token from Discord, no matter the user that processed the OAuth.

It seems i found a solution by changing this:

```
axios.post(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials..
```

into this:

```
axios.post(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code...
```

As we see in your screenshot, you called for a "**response_type=code**" in discord OAuth authorize URL params. Then Discord sends back an "**authorization_code**" instead of a "**client_credentials**".